# Issue calling functions with argparse

Tags: python, function, argparse

I'm having issues calling functions from the command line with argparse. I just want it to execute one of the functions defined in the script.

```
import os
import shutil
import getpass
import argparse


user = getpass.getuser()
copyfolders = ['Favorites']

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('e', action='store')
parser.add_argument('i', action='store')
args = parser.parse_args()


def exp(args):
    for folder in copyfolders:
        c_path = os.path.join("C:", "/", "Users", user, folder)
        l_path = os.path.join("L:", "/", "backup", folder)
        shutil.copytree(c_path, l_path)

def imp(args):
    for folder in copyfolders:
        l_path = os.path.join("L:", "/", "backup", folder)
        c_path = os.path.join("C:", "/", "Users", user, folder)
        shutil.copytree(l_path, c_path)
```

When I try to call it with an argument I get:

> error the follow arguments are required: i

No matter what argument is passed.

Comment: What command are you using from the command line to execute the script?  Where in the script are either of the functions `exp()` or `imp()` ever called (it appears they are only defined)?

Comment: Have you tried with two arguments? 
`python script.py arg1 arg2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of problems here:

1. You can't use [`action`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#action) to call a defined function directly. However, you can set it to a boolean variable value using `action='store_true'` and then define your logic what to do when that variable is true (or false)
2. Your functions [have to be defined before you call them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1909389/1312080) in the script.

This is what ended up working for me:

```
def exp(arg):
    #replace below with your logic
    print("in exp for %s" % arg)

def imp(arg):
    #replace below with your logic
    print("in imp for %s" % arg)

user = getpass.getuser()
copyfolders = ['Favorites']

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

#make sure to prefix the abbreviated argument name with - and the full name with --
parser.add_argument('-e', '--exp', action='store_true', required=False)
parser.add_argument('-i', '--imp', action='store_true', required=False)
args = parser.parse_args()

isExp = args.exp
isImp = args.imp

if isExp:
    exp("foo")

if isImp:
    imp("bar")
```

Also, make sure to prefix the abbreviated argument name with `-` and the full name with `--`.